# ssh fails with "No user exists for uid X" on LDAP user on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ldap, sssd

I have an Ubuntu Laptop connected to Windows AD.

When I use SSH to connect to a server (e.g. `ssh 192.168.1.1`), logged in with an LDAP account, I get the error

```
No user exits for uid 213321
```

- If I use a local account (`root` etc.) the SSH login works fine.
- I already tried to reinstall SSH and reconfigured `sssd` without success.

Comment: "When i use SSH" - *How* are you running SSH? What is the exact command? What is configured in your ssh config? The system is trying to map your AD user ID to a local user ID, which does not exist. (Please don't answer in comments, edit your question instead).

Comment: Did your sssd config change the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and perhaps `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` files?  If so, could you edit your question to add the changes that were made to the files?

Comment: @Sotto Voce i checked both configs they are equal to a working config (we have the same Setup on 3 working laptops). Only one is behaving like that, i cant find any difference in sssd or ssh configurations

Comment: Try running `id 213321` (i.e. try looking up the user with the reported UID) on the failing system and on the working system. Are the responses the same or different? Are there any error messages? To look up usernames from the AD, the system needs its AD *computer account* to be in good standing - perhaps the failing system's computer account has failed to auto-renew and has expired?

Comment: @telcoM both working and not working laptops get the same user back

Comment: On the failing system, logged in with a LDAP account, try running `getent passwd 213321` and `getent passwd $(whoami)`. Are there any error messages? Are the responses the same in both cases?

Comment: yes both where the same, we also cleared the sssd cache and removed the cached ldap db without success. We gave up and created an local user for now....